# Jquery - Function when Div becomes populated

Tags: jquery

I have a div that when the webpage first loads is empty (collectionBin). I have thumbnail images that users can drag and drop into that empty div. I have a div that is hidden that provides options for users. I want this div to become visible only when the empty div (collectionBin) has an image inside of it. I'm not sure if I am explaining this well enough. Below is a link to the page that will hopefully help.

http://www.plantcombos.com/header/main_index.php?display=random_mix&currentpage=1

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How do I make the options div visible once an image has been placed inside the collection bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code here

```
$("#collectionArea").droppable({
    accept: ".selector",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
            $("#collectionArea .product").addClass("item");
            $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable selector");
            $(".item").draggable({
                    containment: "parent",
                    grid: [72,72],
            });
    }
});
```

Try adding a line in the `drop` function: `$("#cbOptions").show()` (or whatever `div` you want to appear).

Comment: That worked perfect and was such a simple solution. I spent hours trying to get this to work. Thank you

Comment: Of course! Glad to help. I often overlook little things like that.